# Why is my framerate taking dips?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

In GTA 5 (PC), my framerate will remain at 60 fps with V-Sync, then will dip to about 20-30 fps with no explanation. My GeForce GTX 970, Intel i7-3820, 16 GB of RAM, and a 7200 RPM harddrive can handle the game just fine.

Comment: Are you running anything else on the PC while playing?

Comment: @TimmyJim Uplay, Origin, sometimes Discord, maybe a few background tasks, but it only slows down randomly with GTA 5. Maybe my computer comes under load when trying to go through each section of the city.

Comment: I've read  and also watched a video saying that background processes may cause this.  Try closing some other windows.  I've also seen that Alt-tabbing out of GTA and back into fixes it.

Comment: Turn V-sync off, when you traverse through flora you may experience frame rate issues.

Comment: I'm not sure how GTA V loads new data, but a HDD may slow you down when going into a new area. It shouldn't affect the fps though.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar PC to you and I have had situations like that as well. I found out the biggest killer of framerate in GTA V happens to be grass. Depending on the area of the map you are in (the Vinewood hills are a prime example.) and quality you set your foliage to these areas can tank your framerate a lot. Try lowering your foliage quality a little bit and you should be able to get more steady FPS.